# Refresh data in System.Data.Entity.DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, xtragrid

We have data stored in SQLite database. Data are shown in DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl. To get relevant data we create temporary table and we fill it.
Data Context:

```
public class AccountsSQLiteDataContext : DbContext
{
    public AccountsSQLiteDataContext(IDbConnection connection)
        : base((SQLiteConnection)connection, false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AccountsSQLiteDataContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<tmp_acc> TmpAccounts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Work With DbContext:

```
AccountsSQLiteDataContext myContext = new AccountsSQLiteDataContext(myDbConnection);

public IQueryable AccountTable
{
    get
    {
        return myContext.TmpAccounts;
    }
}

DevExpress.Data.Linq.LinqServerModeSource myLinqSource =  = new DevExpress.Data.Linq.LinqServerModeSource();
myLinqSource.QueryableSource = AccountTable;
myGridControl.DataSource = myLinqSource;
```

And after data change I call: `myLinqSource.Reload();`

And not all changes in data in SQLite temporary table are shown in grid. Adding and removing of table rows takes effect. But changes in cell texts are not shown. 
Filter functions takes effect with new values. See [printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHwBE.png). In filter options are right values, in grid are old values.

How refresh local data stored in DbContext to show correct values after change in temporary table?

Comment: Are you using the WinForms DataGridView?

Comment: We use DevExpress UI framework with its DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl and DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling the RefreshDataSourceMethod() on the GridControl

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_RefreshDataSourcetopic

Comment: I check this refresh option, it takes no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions. Both of them cancels caching of items in EF data model:

1. use autoincrement field in SQL table, table is recreated after any data change
2. use of AsNoTracking extension method for loading of entities from the database:

   public IQueryable AccountTable
   {
       get
       {
           return myContext.TmpAccounts.AsNoTracking();
       }
   }